# springboot actuator returns 401 for actuator endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am refactoring an old java spring project into springboot, and deploy it in a traditional war style. For some reason I have to stick to traditional web.xml to start the application. Thanks to Springboot legacy, I can achieve this with a web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.MyServerServletConfig</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In addition, I add springboot actuator dependency. The `application.properties` is like below:

```
endpoints.enabled=true
endpoints.sensitive=true
management.security.enabled=true
management.context-path=/manage
security.user.password=myserver
security.user.name=myserver
```

The application can start normally, but when I try to visit endpoints from browser it just returns a `401 Full authentication is required to access this resource` error without asking me to type in username and password. Related logs are below:

```
16:00:04.264 DEBUG [resin-port-8081-19] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: DispatcherServlet with name 'myservlet' processing GET request for [/manage/health]
16:00:04.264 DEBUG [resin-port-8081-19] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Looking up handler method for path /manage/health
16:00:04.264 DEBUG [resin-port-8081-19] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Returning handler method [public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)]
16:00:04.264 DEBUG [resin-port-8081-19] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: Last-Modified value for [/manage/health] is: -1
16:00:04.264 DEBUG [resin-port-8081-19] org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver: Found key 'endpoints.sensitive' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:../conf/application.properties]] with type [String]
16:00:04.265 DEBUG [resin-port-8081-19] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: Successfully completed request
```

What might be the reason for this problem? Is there any difference between a DispatherServlet auto constructed by springboot and one explicitly defined in a web.xml? For security considerations `management.security.enabled=true` is a necessity.

Answer (score 6):

See this part of of the Spring Boot Manual:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html

specifically this section:

48.1 Accessing sensitive endpoints

By marking endpoints as sensitive, you can't see them unless you are logged in with an appropriate role. So you have to set up Spring Security for your sensitive endpoints.

There's a good blog entry here on how to do that:

http://www.devglan.com/spring-security/securing-spring-boot-actuator-endpoints-with-spring-security

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I wonder there are some deeper reasons for this problem. As comparison, I use a servlet 3.0 style to refactor this project, i.e., write a class that extends from SpringbootServletInitializer, which can be auto detected by a web container that supports servlet 3.0, and use that class to config the application and leave other work done by springboot, such as injecting a DispatcherServlet. In this way, with `application.properties` unchanged, the endpoints can be visited after typing in authentication info. I cannot tell why it not works when using web.xml.

Comment: Not sure on that point. Maybe just ditch web.xml as explained here :

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-vs-java-config